Tasks stuck in broker
I have RabbitMQ on a Docker container with result_backed to PostgreSQL (if local it uses SQLite). When running in multiprocessing mode, tasks get stuck in RabbitMQ. Why is that?
If I run Celery with regular pool implementation (multiprocessing), tasks do not return any result (if I don't set timeout it never ends). When I look at the RabbitMQ management console I see that they are stuck in unacked. If I close the Celery app and then reopen it, all those stuck tasks are recalled (task ... received), but they are still stuck.
If I start the app again with -P eventlet or threads, all of the stuck tasks are recalled and resolved (and in RabbitMQ all the unacked messages become ready). Also, when running in multiprocess mode I see no entry in the backend, but when changing to multithreading I see new entries for those tasks called while Celery was in multiprocessing mode.
The task itself is add(x, y): return x+y.

In order to draw any conclusion(s) I need to know two things. 1) how exactly do you run your worker(s) - exact command 2) how do you schedule task to be executed. Are you using apply_async(), delay(), send_task() and how you use these functions exactly (args, kwargs, and other params like queue).

@DejanLekic

celery -A src worker --loglevel=info --logfile=ttt.log
for now I didn't set any scheduled task, I just tried to run a simple:
from tasks import add
r = add.delay(1,1)
print(r.status)
print(r.get(timeout=10))


the task itself is as in the documentation:
@app.task def add(x, y):     return x + y

Are there any entries in the ttt.log file? You should attach to the container, and run that exact Celery worker manually. It could be that when you run it with celery -A src it can't find any tasks so no task is registered, which basically will make Celery worker run there doing nothing.

@DejanLekic
so why running with -P eventlet is working?
in the log I see:
[INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[INFO/MainProcess] celery@mypc ready.
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 180332 calling self.run() (3 times)
[INFO/MainProcess] Task src.tasks.add[dbdaeb5c-6e22-49a7-baec-02509c296792] received
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 16452 calling self.run() (3 times)

it seems like the main process is receiving the task call, but no child process is handling it...

Did you try to specify concurrency with something like: celery -A src worker --loglevel=info --logfile=ttt.log -c 10 (note: I've added -c 10)

@DejanLekic Yes, I've tried to add -c 4 but it doesn't work...
I think I found out the issue, which is not related to the code at all...
it seems that multiprocessing celery does not work well on Windows...
see this link: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5738
If I understand correctly, the default forking method in Windows is not the same as Linux...

and this faq:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows

You should have said you run this on Windows...
